# PUT method is working only 6 times in Node express app

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongodb as my database to update the value of variable. And I'm using node.js and express server.

Here is my code:

```
router.route("/update/").put( async (req, res) =>{
    const count_update = {
        date: new Date(),
        count: req.body.count
    }
    var searchDate = count_update.date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    const auth = req.currentUser;
    if (auth) {
    try{
      await User.updateOne(
          { id: auth.uid },
          [{
            $set: {
              count: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $gt: [searchDate, { $substr: [{ $last: "$count.date" }, 0, 10] }]
                  },
                  {
                    $concatArrays: [
                      "$count",
                      [{ date: count_update.date, count: count_update.count }]
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$count",
                      in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            $cond: [
                              {
                                $eq: ["$$this.date", { $last: "$count.date" }]
                              },
                              { count: count_update.count },
                              {}
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }]
        )
```

This code is updating the variable only 6 times. Then I have to reload the app to update another 6 times.

What might be the problem?

Comment: what's the value of req.body.count ?

Comment: It doesn't have a fixed value, It rapidly changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. It is my server waiting for response. Browser limits the concurrent request limits to 6 or something. That is the problem.

Best way to do this is to end the response waiting by calling:

```
res.end()
```